# Provide a whitelist of words in FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a factory definition that looks like this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :foo do
    name { Faker::Lorem.word }
  end
end
```

Can I provide a custom list of words, so that the name is always going to be one of the words I choose?

Comment: It's just code--you can run whatever you want in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a different set of words than what `Faker::Lorem` might offer then you could simply use that;

```
name { ['my', 'words', ...].sample }
```